# Simple explode operation with Wordpress post titles

Tags: php, wordpress, explode

I have a music reviews blog and I use this format for titles in my wordpress:

> Band - Album

So I want to do something seemingly simple as "explode" the title:

```
$title = get_the_title ();
$str = explode ("-", $title);
$band = $str[0];
$album = $str[1];
echo "Band: ".$band;
echo "<br>Album: ".$album;
```

The problem is that it outputs the whole title in variable $band. Explode doesn't work with hyphen/dash (-). However, if I use any other "separator" in the explode function, it works properly.

Any idea about what's the matter here?

Comment: Are you sure it's a dash, and not just another character that looks the same?

Comment: Use URL encoding, it will give you real code of hyphen/dash. Also you can check by editing manually hyphen/dash in your URL, or any other place from where you are getting the value using "get_the_title" var.

Comment: Please recheck @User016. Anthony-Sterling might be right.

Comment: Yes, it's a dash. In fact if I copy the character output and paste in the code as separator, I get same result

Comment: its working fine in mine, must have some mistake...

Comment: Check if the dash in your title is encoded

Answer (score 3):

Solved! ...with **htmlentities**. Seems that my wordpress encode hyphens with a different code. It may be because the font used in my theme, I don´t know...

```
$title = htmlentities(get_the_title ());
$str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);
$band = $str[0];
$album = $str[1];
echo "Band: ".$band;
echo "<br>Album: ".$album;
```

Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

Created phpfiddle with your data and is working great:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f42-tni

You must have some other char in you string.

Adding code from phpfiddle..

```
<?php
$title = "Band - Album";
$str = explode ("-", $title);
$band = $str[0];
$album = $str[1];
echo "Band: ".$band;
echo "<br>Album: ".$album;
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code to your answer directly. If the link gets broken your answer gets invalid.